# How to Deploy React App from GitHub to Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

Heyy, I was trying to deploy my React App to the Azure App Service using PowerShell. Well, I have to deploy it from GitHub, and use PowerShell.

```
initialize -appCount 1
```

I have a function execution like the above to create N apps. And that function includes the lines below:

```
$PropertiesObject = @{
    repoUrl = "$repoName";
    branch = "main";
    isManualIntegration = "true";
}

New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location

New-AzAppServicePlan -Name $servicePlanName -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tier $tier

New-AzWebApp -Name $webAppName -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AppServicePlan $appServicePlan

Set-AzResource -Properties $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols -ResourceName $webAppName -Force
```

After I execute the script it creates a web app. However, it displays this:

[image: Website after unsuccessful deployment]

And, I get this error without a message.

[image: Powershell error]

I tried to add a GitHub repo manually to test if I can deploy my React app somehow, even though I cannot set up deployment manually. But it gave another error like this:

[image: Deployment Center Error]

My question is how can I deploy my React app from my public GitHub repository by using PowerShell to the Azure App Service?

Comment: Do you need any alternative way to deploy reactjs to azure using GitHub?

Comment: I need to use PowerShell script that pulls the repo and deploy, after that I need to be able to connect a single Azure SQL Database to those apps

Comment: Can you provide your repository link so in can check ?

Comment: Sure, here is the repo, just updated the main branch: https://github.com/OrcunSelbasan/azure-web-app

Comment: which runtime stack are you using ? ex: .NET,node,java or any ?

Comment: It is node, does it automatically specify the runtime stack because I haven't specified it in the shell script

Comment: @OrcunSelbasan - Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-deploy-github?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json) for sample on how to deploy code in your github to webapp using powershell. for more samples on working with powershell on webapp refer to [this documented samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/samples-powershell).

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT - Thanks, but I’ve already checked the first documentation before posting the question. My script is more or less same as that example script.

Comment: @OrcunSelbasan - Based on the portal screenshot shared look like the GitHub you are trying to attach to webapp has failed(cannot find source GitHub token) and that is the reason your code didn't deployed to app service and while requesting the webapp url you are not able to see your application content.

Comment: I have followed the documentation(shared in my earlier response) steps and tired to deploy your github code to one of my webapp. I am able to attach the github but the deployed is failing with multiple error in code. If you are able to attach the github as source control to your webapp and not able see the application changes while requesting to root url. I would suggest to look at the logs --> under Deployment center of your web app as [shown here](https://i.imgur.com/2zM5PrI.png).

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried to deploy using power shell script even I am getting the error. At the same time some steps are missing if you use power shell. Before deploying the file to the repository check whether the code is running in local system or not.
- If I use power hell to deploy the GitHub repository to azure the app is created successfully but the Runtime stack was not selected, example as shown below

[image]

- Your repository doesn't have the **packages** folder.
- The repository that you have provided was not working So, I have used another repository and deployed react app to azure portal using the below steps
- Open azure portal and create App service. after creating app service, Goto **Deployment center** and add the GitHub repository that you want to add to app service as shown below

[image]

- Click on **Branch** it will redirect to GitHub place Goto Actions as shown below

[image]

- Click on the name in the third step in above picture it will Goto the page which is shown below

[image]

- After successful deployment to azure portal click on the link

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I need a way to do it in a shell script because there might be 10 of the same app in different app services. I'm sorry that I didn't understand what you mean by I don't have a packages folder and the repo is not working. It runs locally but fails on the build stage of the deployment if I follow your steps.